# Browser is not storing my cookie

Tags: python, http, cookies

My challenge is sending my cookie along with my payload. I'm simply adding a cookie to an existing, and running program. The payload (song) is getting there just fine. And, I'm not getting any errors at the browser console.

I seem to be able to send a cooke, along with my JSON data just fine.

When I look at the headers in Chrome's Developer's Tools, I see the cookie. But, when I look for the cookie in the Application>>Cookie tab, nothing is there. So, a cookie header seems to be sent, by the client is not storing it.

And, at the client.... document.cookie is null.

My test code is creating a single cookie called sessionID.

Here is the Response Header in Chrome: You can see my fake sessionID cookie:
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:null

Content-Type:text/plain

Date:Wed, 23 Nov 2016 22:41:10 GMT

Server:BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.5.2

Set-Cookie:sessionID=4jjdd7ghhq
```

Here is the screenshot indicating No Cookies. no cookies in application

Here is my server code, written in Python3:

```
def do_OPTIONS(self):
    self.send_response(200)       
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", self.headers["Origin"])
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")            
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    self.end_headers()
    return

def do_GET(self):
    if self.path.startswith("/songs/ID"):
        self.load_cookie()
        db=MediaDB()
        ID = self.parseID(self.path)
        song = db.getSong(ID)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', self.headers["Origin"])
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true") 
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")      
        self.cookie["sessionID"] = "4jjdd7ghhq"
        self.send_cookie()
        self.end_headers()
        json_string = json.dumps(song)
        self.wfile.write(bytes(json_string, "utf-8"))
    elif self.path.startswith("/songs"):
        self.getSongs()
        return
    else:
        self.badPath()
        return  


def load_cookie(self):
    if "Cookie" in self.headers:
        self.cookie = cookies.SimpleCookie(self.headers["Cookie"])
    else:
        self.cookie = cookies.SimpleCookie()
    return

def send_cookie(self):
    for morsel in self.cookie.values():
        self.send_header("Set-Cookie", morsel.OutputString())
    return
```

================

My searches have come up short. If there is something out there that might help me, I appreciate you pointing that out. Oh, by the way, my skin's pretty thick, so if I'm doing something stupid - it's okay to point it out... I gotta learn somehow. ha!

Also, in the event you wonder if it is because Chrome sometimes will not set a cookie if the client and host are on the same system, I've tested around that, with the server on a remote system, and the client on my local host.

Again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.